# How to target a separate database in a SQL Server DML Trigger?

Tags: sql-server, azure, triggers

I've created the following trigger in a separate audit database on the same server as my production database:

```
create trigger [trg_transaction]
on Prod.[dbo].Transaction after insert, update, delete not for replication
as
begin
set NOCOUNT on

declare @operation as char(1)
if exists (select * from inserted)
if exists (select * from deleted)
select @operation = 'U'
else
select @operation = 'I'
else
select @operation = 'D'

insert into Audit (operation, table_name, old_content, new_content)
select
@operation,
'[Prod].Transaction',
    case when d.TransactionID is null then null else (select d.* for xml raw) end,
    case when i.TransactionID is null then null else (select i.* for xml raw) end
    from inserted as i
    full outer join deleted as d on i.TransactionID = d.TransactionID
end
```

However, I receive a syntax error when trying to target [Prod].Transaction.  What is the proper way to reference my Transaction table in my Prod database from the Audit database?

Comment: You can't create a trigger in one database which triggers on a table in another database. You can create your trigger in your prod database and within your trigger write to your audit database.

Comment: I was hoping that wouldn't be the case, but thanks for confirming for me.  Do the triggers used for audit purposes pose a performance hit on the production database?

Comment: All triggers have an effect on performance... but a simple audit trigger should be very fast. And in your case, there is no need to separate out `@operation` as a variable - you can inline that into the query.

Comment: I'd certainly investigate the performance of converting the data to XML.